# PHP Objects with Arrays

Tags: php

I'm working with Amazon's MWS API, PHP library.

I'm hoping to have the information from Amazon converted from how its being given from the API to a simple HTML table.

How do I loop through ObjectArrays and pull the information I want?

All suggestions are appreciated.

PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once('.config.inc.php');
$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
$config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
    'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

$service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config
);

MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrders
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
$request->setSellerId('SELLERID');
$request->setMarketplaceId(array('ATVPDKIKX0DER', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2',     'A1AM78C64UM0Y8'));
$request->setCreatedAfter('2016-05-01');
$request->setOrderStatus(array('Unshipped', 'PartiallyShipped'));

// object or array of parameters
invokeListOrders($service, $request);

function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service,  $request)
    {                  
        try {
            $response = $service->ListOrders($request);
            $mws = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersResponse;

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($response);
            echo '</pre>';

        } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex) {
            echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
            echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
            echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
            echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
            echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
            echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
            echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
       }
 }
```

**Object Output via `print_r`:**

```
MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersResponse Object
(
[_fields:protected] => Array
    (
        [ListOrdersResult] => Array
            (
                [FieldValue] => MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersResult Object
                    (
                        [_fields:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [NextToken] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldValue] => 
                                        [FieldType] => string
                                    )

                                [CreatedBefore] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldValue] => 2016-05-06T19:10:39Z
                                        [FieldType] => string
                                    )

                                [LastUpdatedBefore] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldValue] => 
                                        [FieldType] => string
                                    )

                                [Orders] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldValue] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_Order Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_fields:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [AmazonOrderId] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FieldValue] => 115-7547682-3635468
                                                                        [FieldType] => string
                                                                    )

                                                                [SellerOrderId] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FieldValue] => 
                                                                        [FieldType] => string
                                                                    )

                                                                [PurchaseDate] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FieldValue] => 2016-05-02T17:47:50Z
                                                                        [FieldType] => string
                                                                    )

                                                                [LastUpdateDate] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FieldValue] => 2016-05-05T16:29:23Z
                                                                        [FieldType] => string
                                                                    )

                                                                [OrderStatus] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FieldValue] => Unshipped
                                                                        [FieldType] => string
                                                                    )
```

Comment: Likely there is a method that will retrieve the information you are looking for like `$amazon->getOrders()` which may retrieve the `Orders` array, I don't know the API but that's probably the case. There should be some sort of documentation on this API/SDK no?

Comment: Honestly, the documentation isn't helpful at this point http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/dev_guide/DG_ResponseFormat.html

Comment: What code do you have to get to this point?

Comment: Its Amazon's MWS PHP API. Do you suggest looking through it and try to figure out how it got to this point?

Comment: Well the API s different than the Library that you use to access the API. What script do you have to get to this point?

Comment: You need to look more into the PHP Library you are using, that should have  a method to give you what you need.

Comment: PHP, check the original post to see it

Comment: `$key['value']` for array, `$key->value` for object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fairy tells me you can likely call `->getOrder()` on your `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersResult` object to get the array that iterates over your orders. Try it on `$response` first; I can't tell which one without testing the actual code.
(https://github.com/basio/PlaywithAmazonAWS/blob/278b6256025b2841841bda79b304d5a0818b3325/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Model/OrderList.php#L65)

By the way, it's not an ObjectArray; it's just an array hidden inside that object.